# Why is line not being drawn according to x,y settings I pass?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have an app where I draw vertical lines representing appointments.  They are not being drawn where I want them drawn.  Here is an example of what is currently being drawn:

[image]

This is the pertinent part of the the code that configures x and y for each vertical bar and draws it:

```
//  get shop hours from Preferences
NSDate *timeShopOpens;  //  GMT - 8
NSString *completeDateString;
PreferenceData *prefDataFound = [PreferenceData MR_findFirst];
if(prefDataFound)  {
    completeDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                          [startDateParts objectAtIndex: 0],prefDataFound.aShopOpens];  //  2014-01-27 1000
    timeShopOpens = [formatter dateFromString:completeDateString];  //  NSDate 2014-01-27 18:00:00 +0000
}

//  compute where to start drawing
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                                components:NSCalendarUnitMinute
                                fromDate:timeShopOpens toDate:ai.aStartTime  options:0];
float openAndStartMinutesDiff = [components minute];  //  difference between shopOpen time and appt startTime in minutes
float fWhereToStartSegments = (openAndStartMinutesDiff / 15);  //  gives the number of 15-minute segments to begin drawing
float startPosY = 28.0f + (fWhereToStartSegments * 12.5);   //  compute starting point (adjusted for line width)

//  compute duration segments
components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
              components:NSCalendarUnitMinute
              fromDate:ai.aStartTime toDate:ai.aEndTime  options:0];
float startEndDiffMinutes = [components minute];  //  difference between stop and start time in minutes  <--OK
float fDurationSegments = (startEndDiffMinutes / 15);  //  gives the number of 15-minute segments for duration

NSLog(@"\n\nstartPosY: %f\nopenAndStartMinutesDiff: %f\nfDurationSegments: %f",startPosY, openAndStartMinutesDiff, fDurationSegments);

// Start the line at this point (x,y)
float y = startPosY;
CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext, column, y);

// compute end point  (additional fDurationSegments takes line width into consideration)
CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, column,  startPosY + (fDurationSegments * 12.5) + fDurationSegments);

//  draw the colored line
CGContextSetLineDash(currentContext, 0, nil, 0);  //  reset dashed line to straight line
CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, LINE_WIDTH);  // Set the width for the lines

CGContextStrokePath(currentContext);  //  draw 'em
```

The values for the pertinent objects are listed here and have correct values:

```
timeShopOpens: 2014-01-27 18:00:00 +0000
ai.aStartTimeOpens: 2014-01-27 18:15:00 +0000
startPosY: 40.500000
openAndStartMinutesDiff: 15.000000
fDurationSegments: 4.000000
fWhereToStartSegments: 1.000000
```

Question is: why is it not drawing correctly?

---

I'm looking to get something like this manually created rendition:

[image: image from comments]

Comment: can you add a picture where it shows how it should look like? if we have visual reference it's easier to locate the error in the code.

Comment: lol... can't add a picture of what it should look like 'cause I can't get it to work!  However, if you imagine the top-left red bar, it should start at the 1015 horizontal line and go down to the 1115 line.

Comment: you can use photoshop or whatever to just give a rough sketch, would make it much easier

Comment: Thanks for the edit... didn't think of it... any ideas?  :D

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong, because you show us a picture where you appear to have drawn a bunch of bars correctly, but then tell us that this one is not getting drawn correctly. But you're not telling us what's wrong with it. Not appearing at all? Appearing in the wrong place? Etc.

Comment: As an aside, the line `CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, column,  startPosY + (fDurationSegments * 12.5) + fDurationSegments);` looks suspicious, though. If each segment is 12.5 pt tall, why are you then adding `fDurationSegments` again?

Comment: None of the bars are drawn correctly: they are not positioned correctly vertically nor is the length correct.  I only drew one line to show what it should look like; as I mentioned, they are in the correct position horizontally, but vertically, they don't start at the right place, nor is the length correct.  The addition of fDurationSegments is to take into the horizontal line width.  It's all a vertical positioning and length problem.

Comment: I figured it out... I was using 1/2 of the increment; examined the code where the horizontal lines where drawn, and the increment was incorrect.  Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. In terms of the line length, you have a line that says:

   ```
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, column,  startPosY + (fDurationSegments * 12.5) + fDurationSegments);
   ```

   You say you do this to "take into the horizontal line width" [?], but I'm not sure what you mean. If your line should be 4 segments tall, if `fDurationSegments` is `4.0`, you just want:

   ```
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, column,  startPosY + fDurationSegments * 12.5);
   ```

   But your code would make it, using my example, `startPosY + (4.0 * 12.5) + 4.0`. Why add, for example, an extra four points for your hour-long segments and an extra six points for your 90 minute segments? I don't understand why you're adding `fDurationSegments` to the value, but it is a function of the number of segments, not the line width. I must be misunderstanding your intent here.
2. On the basis of what you shared with us, this is unlikely be to an issue, but you want want to confirm your line cap, too. You haven't shared with us your `CGContextSetLineCap` setting, but you definitely want to use `kCGLineCapButt` rather than `kCGLineCapSquare`. I think this is what it defaults to, but it might be prudent to explicitly set it. If you use `kCGLineCapSquare` it will make the line longer than you want (by an amount equal to half of the line width). `kCGLineCapButt` will make it precisely the length you specify, regardless of line width.
3. Also, I don't know if the image you showed us is the actual screen capture, or whether you resized it at all, but it looks like the grid has been rendered at 75.0 pts / hour. That means that the height of each 15 minute segment would be `18.75`, not `12.5`. This would affect both line length as well as the `startPosY`.

   Perhaps you resized the image before uploading it, in which that point is moot, but bottom line, I'd suggest you confirm the scale you used for rendering the bars with the scale you used for rendering the grid behind the bars.

Comment: By the way, if your grid is really 75.0 pts/hour, I might suggest using a value that is divisible by four, e.g. 76.0 or 80.0. You're less likely to get undesirable anti-aliasing in your rendering of these 15-minute segments.